# Assigning values to different variable in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I have two different array with values as below:

```
Code = [8,9,10]
Value = [4,5,6]
```

I need to get the values from each array (above mentioned) randomly and assign it to different variable like below:

```
 Code 1 = 9 , Code2=10
 Value1 = 4 , Value2=6
```

Or is there any way in Jmeter to Pass that array to another sampler thereby assigning it to different variables.

How can we achieve it on Jmeter ? Any help / Suggestions is welcome!

Comment: Could you please explain more, are these Jmeter variables, beanshell or groovy variables?

Comment: @ararar , those were Jmeter variables. attached my sample code herewith.

Comment: @ararar , https://www.screencast.com/t/SvJmS5BmJq

Answer (score 1):

Your values look utterly like [JSON Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) so my expectation is that you could handle it more easy using [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

Just in case I'm wrong you can get random code and/or value using the following Groovy code in any of [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils

def codes = vars.get('Code').findAll(/\d+/ )*.toInteger()
def values = vars.get('Value').findAll(/\d+/ )*.toInteger()

def randomCode = codes.get(RandomUtils.nextInt(0,codes.size()))
def randomValue = values.get(RandomUtils.nextInt(0,values.size()))

log.info('Random code: ' + randomCode)
log.info('Random value: ' + randomValue)
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Demo]

Comment: Thanks. But i need to select two values from the list and assign it to two different variables. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Config Element" > "Random Variable" where you can give a range and ask for a random number within that given range.

Hope it helps.